# Why would a ssh password-based login fail?

Tags: ssh, password, root

I currently use ssh keys to connect to my server (Ubuntu 18.04). I would like to allow (in a specific, limited scope) the ability to login with passwords.

Whenever I try, my passwords fail. below is a session where I set a password, then try to use it:

```
~ # id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

~ # passwd
Enter new UNIX password: <helloworld>
Retype new UNIX password: <helloworld>
passwd: password updated successfully

~ # ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no root@127.0.0.1
The authenticity of host '127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:AlFtwpK4EhhaMXP5aT6fuQM9u9RYPq/o/sLJXfz++jM.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '127.0.0.1' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@127.0.0.1's password: <helloworld>
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I apologize if this is something obvious, I have no clue why the server accepts a new password, then accepts a password-based login to finally reject the credentials.

EDIT: the `sshd_config` file I failed to add

```
~ # cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep -v ^#  | grep -v ^$                                                                                                                  root@srv
Port 22
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
PrintMotd no
UseDNS no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Match Address 192.168.10.0/24,192.168.20.0/24,127.0.0.0/8
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Can you show us your sshd_config file? Could be many things. Maybe `PermitRootLogin no` is configured as well

Comment: `PermitRootLogin` defaults to `prohibit-password`, so password login is disabled for `root`. Use a different user or change the setting to `yes` and try again.

Comment: @Freddy: that was it, thank you. Would you mind copying that to an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: running `ssh -v` may be helpful

Comment: @WoJ I really don't mind if you answer your question. You tested it and fixed it, not me ;)

Comment: @Freddy: I just added a line at the bottom, which I would never found out myself. If you just draft an answer I can then edit it with more details, links etc. Thanks anyway for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The login failed, because there is no setting for `PermitRootLogin` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` which defaults to `prohibit-password`, which means password login is disabled for `root`.

Adding

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

to the `Match` block would allow `root` to login with password or public key authentication.

Another option would be to use a different user.